# Default Launcher still running and using RAM. How can I stop it without root?

Tags: launcher, miui-12.5, redmi-note-10-pro, miui-13

I am running a stock MIUI system launcher on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro. Today, I changed my launcher to Nova Launcher, and set it as default. And, I tried to force stop the MIUI System Launcher, but failed. It continues using about 150MB of RAM. How can I stop running this app and reduce RAM/battery usage?

*(Previously I used Motorola with Moto Launcher. I installed Pixel Launcher over it. And, there I can force stop Moto Launcher, which will start again at next reboot)*

Comment: It uses the RAM but not much of battery. Anyway forcing system applications would break system functionality. Moto launcher is close to stock launcher but MIUI is quite opposite. It is too far away from stock launcher. I'm sure it will break other things like notification shade, gestures etc. 150Mb is not much if we consider 6Gb-8Gb of RAM today in Android mobiles. Why do you want that extra memory for?

Comment: @MANI its just to understand facts. I thought UI become lighter after force close heavy miui system launcher.